# fork() in a for loop with 2 iterations

Tags: c, for-loop, operating-system, fork, parent-child

What will be the output of the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
int i;

for (i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    fork();

    printf("1\n");
}

printf("2\n");

}
```

On the lectures, the professor ran the code and the output had six 1s and four 2s, but I don't understand how we obtained those numbers.

Comment: have you tried running the code on pencil and paper?

Comment: yes, but I don't get it how the number of 1s is 6, i get 4

Comment: unrelated: `void main()` ==> `int main(void)`

Comment: Also `#include <unistd.h>` for proper prototypes

Comment: You might understand it better if you did `printf("1 PID = %d Parent = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());`

Comment: It depends!  Is output to a tty or to a file?  The buffering can make a difference.  If the output is line buffered, then the output will be consistent.  if the output is block buffered (which will be the default if the process is writing to a file) the output may be different each time you run the program.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: agree on different outputs... but no matter what (in the absence of errors, stray cosmic rays, or other strange stuff) the output will have 6 `"1"`s and 4 `"2"`s

Comment: There will always be exactly 4 twos and at least 6 ones, but there can be 7 or 8 ones in the output.  But this detail will merely cause confusion at this point.  Add an `fflush` after the `printf` and worry about this when the time is right.  The issue is that `printf` does not write any data, it just sticks it in an internal buffer.  if you do not flush the output, then the buffer is duplicated by the fork and written out by both parent and child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets "draw" the processes in a tree form, and mark out where the `printf` call are happening, and then count the `printf` calls of each type:

```
                      parent
                        |
                      fork
                        ^
         parent -------/ \------------ child
           |                             |
        printf("1")                   printf("1")
           |                             |
     loop iterates                 loop iterates
           |                             |
          fork                          fork
           ^                             ^
 parent --/ \----- grandchild   child --/ \----- grandchild
   |                  |           |                 |
printf("1")       printf("1")  printf("1")       printf("1")
   |                  |           |                 |
loop ends         loop ends    loop ends         loop ends
   |                  |           |                 |
printf("2")       printf("2")  printf("2")       printf("2")
   |                  |           |                 |
proc ends         proc ends    proc ends         proc ends
```

As we can see there are six `printf("1")` calls, and four `printf("2")` calls.

<sub>[I haven't added the newlines in the `printf` calls, the diagram only is for counting the number of calls. Actual output may differ depending on buffering depending on `stdout` target.]</sub>